# Curve val_loss and loss in keras after training a model

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, cnn, data-science-model

I trained a Keras model to diagnose disorders and want to make sure it is good enough to start deploying.
From the below graph, can anyone advise me as to whether my model is overfitting or underfitting?

[image]

Comment: What loss is this? MSE? Binary cross entropy?

Answer (score 1):

Mmm. `Overfitting` and `underfitting` are some important issues to train a model.

The reason these cures might be small dataset, unoptimzed model structure, improper training methods.

So I suggest you as follows:

1. Please collect more data. If there are not enough data to be collected, you should use data augmentation method.

Please reference searching this keyword: `virtual adversarial pattern for data augmentation`

2. To avoid overfitting, you should add `Dropout Layer` or give some `penalty` to layers or add `regularization` rules to the input layer.
3. To avoid `underfitting`, you can change training method.

Please try to change `batch_size`, `epoch`, and `optimization` method.